# To display the category of a specific custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I apologize for my English, but I am French. In my custom search page I display the results of my custom post type and everything is good. Only, I would like to display above the custom post type the category that is his. To display the post categories I do:

```
$category = get_the_category ();
echo "<p> Category:". $category[0]->cat_name. "</ p>";
```

But how to do for custom post type?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  Do you have a custom taxonomy created for your post type?

Comment: yes, I have several

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a custom post type, use `get_the_terms()` instead:

```
<?php $post_terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'your-taxonomy' ); ?>
<p> Category: <?php echo $post_terms[0]->name; ?></p>
```

Much like the results from `get_the_category`, the returned value of `get_the_terms()` is an array of term objects for the taxonomy that you specify when calling the function.  In the example code, that is "your-taxonomy".

This sample code will only display the first term if multiple terms are assigned to a post.  That is the 'zero position' in the array.  Any subsequent terms would be returned in `$post_terms[1]`, `$post_terms[2]`, etc

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

Comment: Super it works!
I will look for "get_the_term"
Thank you so much.